# Installing Passenger + Passenger process is not started

Tags: linux, apache, passenger, centos6

I want  to InstallPassenger + Apache on a Linux/Unix production server
for Node.js apps + Red Hat 6 / CentOS 6 (with RPM) and I have installed it but at the end of the installation this is the output I get:

> ```
> Installed:
>   mod_passenger.x86_64 0:5.1.8-1.el6
>
> Dependency Installed:
>   passenger.x86_64 0:5.1.8-1.el6
>
> Failed:
>   httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-60.el6.centos.5
> ```

When I try also to check if passenger process is running I found it is not.  How can I start the process, I am accusing the failure of  httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-60.el6.centos.5 to be the reason but I do not not where to start from to solve the issue; I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Apache did not install successfully, that's what the `Failed: httpd` means.

Comment: what should I do so that Apache install successfully? I tried to run: passenger-install-apache2-module --apxs2-path='/usr/bin/apxs'  and I got this output: 
The Phusion Passenger Apache module is correctly installed :-)

The command of check if the process of passenger is running shows there is no passenger process running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apache, then you should make sure Apache is installed.

```
yum update 
yum remove httpd 
yum install httpd
```

Passenger integration just drops a module in an existing Apache install, and only starts if Apache also starts.

If you can't get Apache to work you can also use Passenger in [standalone mode](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/standalone/install/oss/).

Comment: I would like to install it in standalone mode but documentation is not showing how to deploy a node.js app in standalone mode.

Comment: Sure it does: [Deploying a Node.js application
on Passenger Standalone](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/deploy/nodejs/)

Comment: OnixSO thanks it's perfect ..now I have two node.js app for which I want to use passenger I would like both to run under ssl (https) and also using the first will be accessed from a subdomain of my website domain and the second another specific domain name still using standalone...is there any documentation which can show me deep configuration such this?

Comment: and I am scared to run:  yum remove httpd 
yum install httpd since apache is installed and there are websites running on my vps(centos 6) ... I think running that will remove all the configurations which is dangerous because I am a newbie in linux adminstration...

Comment: As I told you in above comment I cannot uninstall httpd and  with standalone the passenger process is not starting still.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation I linked? The same section talks about [Letting Passenger handle SSL itself](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html) or [Using Apache for SSL with Passenger Standalone behind it](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/proxy_ssl.html). Neither of these methods require you to run `yum remove httpd` if you don't want to.